# How we can Find cause of CTS Error?

Tags: android, testing, cts

I found some CTS errors which are given below:

Compatibility Test Case: `CtsAppTestCases`
Package Name: `android.app.cts.DialogTest`

Error:

```
-- testContextMenu   fail   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError                      
                              at android.app.cts.DialogTest.testContextMenu(DialogTest.java:971)`

-- testTabScreen     fail   java.lang.RuntimeException: Intent {   
                              act=Activity lifecycle incorrect: received              
                              onResume but expected onStop at 5 }
                              at android.app.cts.ActivityTestsBase.waitForResultOrThrow(ActivityTestsBase.java:149)

-- testTabScreen     fail   java.lang.RuntimeException: Intent {   
                              act=Activity lifecycle incorrect: received              
                              onResume but expected onStop at 5 }
                              at android.app.cts.ActivityTestsBase.waitForResultOrThrow(ActivityTestsBase.java:149)

-- testScreen        fail   java.lang.RuntimeException: Intent { act=Activity
                            lifecycle incorrect: received onResume but expected onStop    
                              at 5 } 
                              at android.app.cts.ActivityTestsBase.waitForResultOrThrow(ActivityTestsBase.java:149)`
```

Answer (score 0):

This Test is expecting the lifecycle as **onPause()** then **onStop()**, but **onResme()** was called rather than **onStop()**.
According to [Android Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) – **“After receiving this call you will usually receive a following call to onStop() (after the next activity has been resumed and displayed), however in some cases there will be a direct call back to onResume() without going through the stopped state.”**
So, it is not mandatory to get desired sequence.